# Parse JSON using jackson with related entities on Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to parse a jcelulas object that has a few many to one relationships. I can't seem to parse them correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jcelulas", catalog = "7jogos")
public class Jcelulas implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Jconcorrentes jconcorrentes;
    private Jgrelhas jgrelhas;
    private Jcodigos jcodigos;
    private Jpremios jpremios;
    private boolean checked;
    private Date dataChecked;

    // getters and setters

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ConcorrentesId")
    public Jconcorrentes getJconcorrentes() {
        return this.jconcorrentes;
    }

    public void setJconcorrentes(Jconcorrentes jconcorrentes) {
        this.jconcorrentes = jconcorrentes;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jtabuleiros/play/commit", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse playcelula(@ModelAttribute DataJson celula,@RequestBody String json) {
    System.out.println(celula.toString());
    System.out.println(json);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

        // read from file, convert it to user class
        Jcelulas user = mapper.readValue(json, Jcelulas.class);

        // display to console
        System.out.println(user);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return new JsonResponse("OK","");
}
```

Request:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "jconcorrentes":1,
   "jgrelhas":1,
   "jcodigos":1
}
```

How should I parse jconcorrentes? I tried as an int and got the following error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.setelog.spring.model.Jconcorrentes] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.setelog.spring.model.Jcelulas["jconcorrentes"])
```

Jconcorrentes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jconcorrentes", catalog = "7jogos")
public class Jconcorrentes implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    ....
    private Date dataRegisto;
    private Set<Jcelulas> jcelulases = new HashSet<Jcelulas>(0);

}
```

PS: These models were generated with hibernate from the mysql database

Comment: Can you share your `Jconcorrentes` class? The problem seems to be with it.

Comment: Added the jconcorrentes model. But these models were generated by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `jconcorrentes` is being serialized as a number, not JSON Object. So Jackson does not know how to construct a `Jconcorrentes` out of value `1`.